# How to REDUCE decimal values from a value of type 'double' in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, double

This is probably a really simple question but, is there a simple way to go from

```
Double myLongNumber = 50.12345678998658576546
```

to

```
Double myLongNumber = 50.1234
```

?

I just want to reduce the number of decimal digits, not remove them all.

Comment: But these are two different numbers then. If you want to *display* a Double with less fraction digits, use String.format("%.3f", myLongNumber).

Comment: @ChristophDahlen that makes sense! If you answer the question with that same message i will be happy to mark it as resolved. Thank you!

Comment: One thing to note is that after you do this, you will *not* have a value of exactly 50.1234.  It will probably be something like 50.12339999999999.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to *change* that number, you can do something like

```java
Double myNotSoLongNumber = Math.round(myLongNumber * 1E4) / 1E4;
```

If you want to display a Double with less fraction digits, use

```java
String myLongNumberAsString = String.format("%.4f", myLongNumber);
```

Comment: This apporach fails to round properly when 1) the product `myLongNumber * 1E4`  exceeds `double` range 2) sometimes when product is inexact and near xxx.5.  Not a robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below options

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.math.RoundingMode;
import java.util.Locale;
import org.apache.commons.math3.util.Precision;

class DoubleTrimmer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Double myLongNumber = 50.12345678998658576546;

        //Option1. just trim the number
        Double trimmedNumber  = Double.valueOf(String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%.4f", myLongNumber));
        System.out.println(trimmedNumber);

        //Option2. Round the number using BigDecimal
        trimmedNumber = round(myLongNumber, 4);
        System.out.println(trimmedNumber);

        //Option3. Round the number using Apache commons math
        trimmedNumber = Precision.round(myLongNumber, 4);
        System.out.println(trimmedNumber);
    }

    public static double round(double value, int places) {
        if (places < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();

        BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(value);
        bd = bd.setScale(places, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        return bd.doubleValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the many options you gave in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use BigDecimal package

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
public class ReduceDecimalNumbers {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double myLongNumber = 50.12345678998658576546;
        int decimalsToConsider = 4;
        BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(myLongNumber );

        bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(myLongNumber );
        BigDecimal roundedValueWithDivideLogic = bigDecimal.divide(BigDecimal.ONE,decimalsToConsider,BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
        System.out.println("Rounded value with Dividing by one = "+roundedValueWithDivideLogic);

    }
}
```

output:

```
   Rounded value with Dividing by one = 50.1235
```

or you can try this

```
    public class round{
       public static void main(String args[]){
    
       double myLongNumber = 50.12345678998658576546;
       double roundOff = Math.round(myLongNumber *1E4)/1E4;
    
       System.out.println(String.format("%.4f", roundOff));   //%.4f defines decimal precision you want
      }
   }
```

output:

```
50.1235
```

Comment: 50.12345678998658576546 rounded to 6 decimal places is 50.1234, not 50.1235. This rounding uses the round to nearest even rule, which is the universally accepted rule for rounding.  Even if you are simply truncating, the result is still 50.1234.

Comment: do you know how to fix this